# React dynamically adding html elements/

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React.  I currently have a component. This component has a title and a body. The body can have several paragraphs and I want to dynamically add the elements depending on how many paragraphs each has. So right now I have this:

```
import React from 'react';

class Content extends React.Component{
    render(){
        var props_list = this.props;
        var keys = Object.keys(props_list);
        console.log(props_list["title"]);

        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
            console.log(props_list[keys[i]]);
        }

        return (
            <div className="introduction">
                <h3>{props_list["title"]}</h3>
                <div className="div-content">

                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Content;
```

Now with this code I can get all the props and information that it's added to each component but I have no clue how to add this information dynamically into the div-content.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It is not clear what you want each paragraph to look like, or what collection of things you want to display. Are you trying to display each of the non-title props and their values?

Comment: You can render an array of html elements, components, and primitives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So. If we could know more about the shape of the props passed into this component it would help but this should be enough to get you going.

```
import React from 'react';

class Content extends React.Component{
   render(){
    var props_list = this.props;
    var keys = Object.keys(props_list);
    console.log(props_list["title"]);
            const paragraphs = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
        console.log(props_list[keys[i]]);
        // This part is to make sure you are not re-rendering your title.
        if(keys[i] !== "title"){
            paragraphs.push(<p>{props_list[keys[i]]}</p>);
        }      
    }

    return (
        <div className="introduction">
            <h3>{props_list["title"]}</h3>
            <div className="div-content">
              {paragraphs}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works perfectly however you have to add {props_list[keys[i]]} or it won't render as a variable.

Comment: excellent. Glad it worked. I'll edit the above.